# Extracting a value from python variable

Tags: python, arrays, variables, extract

When I run the following code I get an output containing a value (1.11113) that I want to use within the code (after this first section). The full outputI get is shown after the code. Basically what I'm trying to do is extract a real time forex (stock) value to use in an order. This order would be placed after this initial code within the same python module. Thanks for your help.

```
import json
from oandapyV20.contrib.requests import MarketOrderRequest
from oandapyV20.contrib.requests import TakeProfitDetails, StopLossDetails
import oandapyV20.endpoints.orders as orders
import oandapyV20
import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing
from exampleauth import exampleAuth
import argparse
from oandapyV20 import API
from oandapyV20.exceptions import V20Error
import oandapyV20.endpoints.instruments as instruments
from oandapyV20.definitions.instruments import CandlestickGranularity
import re
import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing

# pricef=float(price)
# parser.add_argument('--price', choices=price, default='M', help='Mid/Bid/Ask')
accountID, access_token = exampleAuth()
api = oandapyV20.API(access_token=access_token)

params = {"instruments": "EUR_USD"}
r = pricing.PricingInfo(accountID=accountID, params=params)
rv = api.request(r)

print(rv)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'prices': [{'asks': [{'liquidity': 10000000, 'price': '1.11132'}],
             'bids': [{'liquidity': 10000000, 'price': '1.11113'}],
             'closeoutAsk': '1.11132',
             'closeoutBid': '1.11113',
             'instrument': 'EUR_USD',
             'quoteHomeConversionFactors': {'negativeUnits': '1.00000000',
                                            'positiveUnits': '1.00000000'},
             'status': 'tradeable',
             'time': '2020-05-31T23:02:34.271983628Z',
             'tradeable': True,
             'type': 'PRICE',
             'unitsAvailable': {'default': {'long': '3852555',
                                            'short': '3852555'},
                                'openOnly': {'long': '3852555',
                                             'short': '3852555'},
                                'reduceFirst': {'long': '3852555',
                                                'short': '3852555'},
                                'reduceOnly': {'long': '0', 'short': '0'}}}],
 'time': '2020-05-31T23:02:40.672716661Z'}
```

Comment: If you're trying to navigate to the value it's: `rv['prices'][0]['bids'][0]['price']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is a dictionary with a number of nested lists and dictionaries.

To access a value from a dictionary, you use the same syntax as when accessing members of a list, only that the key does not have to be a number, but can be any data type, commonly Strings. So `rv['time']` in your case would yield `'2020-05-31T23:02:40.672716661Z'`.

Since the number 1.11113 appears twice in the dictionary, here are the two pointers that would access the corresponding field:

`rv['prices'][0]['bids'][0]['price']`

and

`rv['prices'][0]['closeoutBid']`

This will be in String format, so to use it as a number, you would have to convert it using `float()`

Also notice the occasional `[0]` to access the first element of a list.

Comment: Perfect!!! It's working like a charm! Also thanks for the explanation for next time!

Comment: @Michael Welcome to StackOverflow! Do not forget to upvote if an answer helps. Also accept the best answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
rv['prices'][0]['bids'][0]['price']
```

at least for this case.  It might not be that you always want the first price entry or the first bid entry, in which case you might want to do some sort of sorting or filtering on whatever criteria you want to use to pick the right entry from among more than one.